# RRelief Feature Selection, using multisurf from skrebate

Tags: python-3.x, feature-selection

I am new to using the MultiSURF algorithm for feature selection.

I am using MultiSurf from skrebate.

I have ~6500 feature dataset.

The code took about 3 days to create a ditance array. It has been stuck on "Feature Scoring unedr way..." for the past 5 days.

What am i doing wrong ?

Following is the code:

```
    
    fs = MultiSURF(n_features_to_select=100,  verbose=True)

    fs.fit(X, y)

    print("Printing for FS")
    print(fs.feature_importances_)
    print(fs.top_features_)
    print("Done Printing for FS")

    dfDashboard = pd.DataFrame()

    for feature_name, feature_score in zip(df.drop(responseCol, axis=1).columns,
                                           fs.feature_importances_):
        print(feature_name, '\t', feature_score)

        new_record = pd.DataFrame([[feature_name, feature_score]],columns=['FeatureName','Score'])
        dfDashboard = pd.concat([dfDashboard,new_record])
```

Can someone please help understand ?
Does MultiSurf not work well for datasets with 1000's features?

Thanks